# Logical and physical addressing

Tags: memory-management

When we talking about logical addresses in the statement `int a` (Is `a` represents the logical memory?). Otherwise what is logical address can you give me a real time example?.

Comment: Please add more details to your question. I assume the answer you demand is "we only deal with logical addresses unless we develop a kernel", but your question is not specific enough to give any such statement.

Comment: Every address you come across in user space is logical address. variable a is stored on the stack, when you do &a, what you get is the locgical address, OR when you do malloc(100) in your program, what you get back is a logical address to 100 bytes of memory...

Comment: @Deepthought That is not entirely true, because there are systems (mainly uCs) without an MCU. I suspect the OP did not ask for those systems, but a complete answer would have to include this information IMO.

Answer (score 0):

`int a`, assuming C/C++ is on the stack.

`int* a` (i.e. the memory it points to) may be at any place in memory.

Unless you are developing a kernel, both exclusively deal with logical addresses -- unless of course you are using a system like ARM CM3 without a MMU. This type of system does not understand logical addresses, but can only handle physical addresses.